# Question is on hold now. Yet my flag got declined

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, declined-flags, on-hold

I'm referring to the question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016160/library-to-convert-java-source-files-into-object-models.

I flagged that question as `very low quality.`

Now it is in `ON HOLD` state. Yet my flag with a reason

> very low quality – sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ | 1 hour ago |  **declined** - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.

Can anyone explain me here, what I'm missing here?

Should I avoid flagging while putting them on hold ?

Comment: If you feel that a question should be closed then **vote to close it** don't flag it as VLQ.

Comment: @Servy Ok. I'l avoid that. Just wanted to know.

Comment: You voted to close and flagged as low quality, why?

Comment: @bluefeet Apologies from my side. After reading anonymous answer, I realized my mistake.

Comment: The flag was declined *precisely because* the question successfully reached on-hold status without a moderator having to do anything about it.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh ok. I don't know this and just wanted to know. I should not flag after I voted to close. Thankyou.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like the decline reason says:

> Flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention.

Moderators deal with *tons* of flags, so if the question simply need to be closed, you should either vote-to-close or submit a *close* flag (depending on your privileges). Flagging a post for anything other than closure should only be used if something *requires* moderator intervention.  If a few users can handle it, there is no need to fill the moderator flag queue.

Even if a moderator had not handled this flag, the very low quality flag is meant for posts that are such low quality that they may need to be deleted. If all closed questions were thrown into the low quality queue, well, it would be as large as the close vote queue. This would also mean that it needs to pass through two different reviews, close votes and very low quality. That is not needed.

Comment: Note that moderators very rarely handle VLQ flags.  One apparently did here, but this is by far not the normal case.  *Usually* VLQ flags are handled by non-moderator users.

Comment: @Servy Good point, I'll update it.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer Anonymous. I don't know this. Will follow.

Comment: This is the answer. Involve moderators when there aren't normal means to handle an issue. Do not involve us to 'bypass' the normal community moderation that should occur.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Sure George, will keep in mind.

Comment: I appreciated this answer because the flags are not very clear about what goes to moderators and what goes to community vote. "Flag for moderator attention" is the only one that intuitively goes to a mod. The other flags don't say anything about moderators so one wouldn't just infer that. I just had a VLQ flag declined, and it is a VLQ question, but I guess I could lie and put it under "too broad" or something to have the community close it.

Comment: @leigero The flags go to moderators for spam, offense, and other. All others go to community vote (including very low quality). A moderator just happened to review this flag in this case.